# Unable to run cucumber test from command line - Success build response (No errors)

Tags: maven, selenium-webdriver, cucumber-junit

> Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date - getting this
>   response from maven-compiler-plugin and no test cases are being
>   executed for Selenium - Cucumber Test Runner file
>
> Changed the TestRunner name ending with test. Added the below
>   configuration in POM.xml file

```
         <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.18</version>
    <configuration>
    <includes>
    <excludes>**/*TestRunnertest.java</excludes>
    </includes>
    </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

### POM.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>corporate</groupId>
  <artifactId>web</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>web</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>


<properties>

 <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>
  <build>
    <plugins>

    <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId> 
    <version>3.6.1</version>
    </plugin>


  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.18</version>
    <configuration>
    <includes>
    <excludes>**/*TestRunnertest.java</excludes>
    </includes>
    </configuration>
    </plugin>

  </plugins>
  </build>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
    <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.7</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>3.141.59</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
    <version>3.141.59</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>junit</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
  <version>4.11</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-email</artifactId>
    <version>1.5</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.directory.studio</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.apache.commons.io</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
</dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

### TestRunner

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        features = "/Users/neha/eclipse-workspace/webCorp/src/test/java/feature", //the path of the feature files
        glue={"stepDefinition"}, //the path of the step definition files
        //format = { "pretty", "json:target/json/output.json" }, 
        tags = { "~@ignore" },
        plugin= {"com.cucumber.listener.ExtentCucumberFormatter:target/cucumber-reports/report.html"}, //to generate different types of reporting
        monochrome = true, //display the console output in a proper readable format`enter code here`
        strict = true, //it will check if any step is not defined in step definition file
        dryRun = false //to check the mapping is proper between feature file and step def file

        )

public class TestRunnertest  {

    @BeforeClass
    public static void startup() {
        System.out.println("Starting test");
    }
}
```

- I expect to be able to run the TestRunner file from commandline using
  the cmd mvn test
  -Dcucumber.options=”/Users/neha/eclipse-workspace/webCorp/src/main/java/testRunner/TestRunner.java”

  I am able to run the code from eclipse by removing cucumber-java, junit and cucmber-junit dependency from pom.xml

Comment: Any error message?

Comment: No Error message. 
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  7.705 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-01-28T18:29:00+04:00

Comment: The runner should be in the src/test/java folder structure and not in the src/main/javato run automatically. Also the runner name needs to contain "test" refer this - https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/inclusion-exclusion.html to be picked up by surefire. No need for any exclusion or inclusion.

Comment: Thanks that helped to run the TestNG class with results as below                                        -------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running TestSuite
Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.695 sec - in TestSuite

Results :

Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS

Comment: I got the results running by extending TestRunner with extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests. However, my test runner fails and gives error cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: Failed to instantiate public cucumber.runtime.java.JavaBackend

Comment: Can you please help with the above error?I am unable to resolve. Tried updating all dependencies to the latest one but still same error

Comment: If u are using testng then u need to include cucumber-testng jar instead of junit one

Answer (score 0):

**Create TestNG.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">

<suite name="Suite" parallel="false">
  <test name="Test">
    <classes>
      <class name="PackageName.TestRunnertest"/>
    </classes>
  </test> <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

**Create pom.xml**

Adding Dependencies and plugin TestNG.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>MavenOutlook</groupId>
  <artifactId>MavenOutlook</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <properties>
  <selenium.version>3.12.0</selenium.version>
  <testng.version>6.9.10</testng.version>
 </properties>

 <dependencies>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
   <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
   <version>3.12.0</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
   <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
   <version>6.9.10</version>
   <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.17</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
      <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
      <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.4</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
      <artifactId>cucumber-picocontainer</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.4</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
      <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.2</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>com.vimalselvam</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-extentsreport</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
    <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.2</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
            <groupId>com.relevantcodes</groupId>
            <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
            <version>2.41.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.22.1</version>
  <type>maven-plugin</type>
</dependency>
 </dependencies>

 <build>
<plugins>
   <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>1.3</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.2-beta-5</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.8</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.3.2</version>
        </plugin>
   <plugin>

     <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>2.19</version>
    <configuration>
     <suiteXmlFiles>
      <suiteXmlFile>TestNG.xml</suiteXmlFile>
     </suiteXmlFiles>
    </configuration>
   </plugin>

  </plugins>
 </build>

</project>
```

Open a command prompt and go to the project directory

And run the test mvn test

Comment: Thanks @Sandeep k. Is it not possible to do without TestNG xml?

Comment: I tried running the above code and now get the below error                                                   Executing Maven:  -N -B -f /Users/neha/.jenkins/workspace/CorporateWebsite/Users/neha/eclipse-workspace/webCorp/pom.xml clean install
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at jenkins.maven3.agent.Maven33Main.launch(Maven33Main.java:176)

Comment: i have added only testng xml to run the TestRunner file. If i run the POM xml, it successfully builds but no test run                                                 Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0                                                
 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------[INFO]          
                   BUILD SUCCESS